# What is the best choice of algorithms for good supervised classification in our data?

Tags: svm, cross-validation, feature-selection

I'm a novice in machine learning-based classification techniques. Please do help

1) What is the difference between SMO (weka) and the LibSVM algorithms? Which is the best? Because the parameter requirements of the two are very different.

2) Feature reduction (e.g.PCA) and feature selection (e.g. InfoGain) are two different techniques for reducing features. Which one to rely on? In which conditions are they to be used?

3) In Infogain eval, the ranking algorithm ranks the features and the threshold parameter can remove the unwanted features with respect to entropy measure. Can we optimize both? Or do we optimize one of them alternatively? What I should I be looking for - accuracy?

4) Is accuracy the only thing that I should be looking for? Of course there is overfitting, but can I quantify the predictive power of the model other than just CV accuracy? Some other measure or technique?

Answer (score 3):

> 1) What is the difference between SMO (weka) and the LibSVM algorithms? Which is the best? Because the parameter requirements of the two are very different.

SMO is a clever way to solve SVM training problems. LibSVM implements SMO. The fact Weka uses different parameters than LibSVM has little to do with SMO, but rather they parameterize the training problem itself differently. Both are essentially equivalent. In fact, [Weka uses LIBSVM](https://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM).

> 2) Feature reduction (e.g.PCA) and feature selection (e.g. InfoGain) are two different techniques for reducing features. Which one to rely on? In which conditions are they to be used?

If you're going to be using SVM, neither feature reduction nor feature selection are required. Typically, they contribute very little to overall performance. For other learning algorithms your mileage may vary. Won't answer (3) as it's irrelevant.

> 4) Is accuracy the only thing that I should be looking for? Of course there is overfitting, but can I quantify the predictive power of the model other than just CV accuracy? Some other measure or technique?

Accuracy is a fairly bad metric to optimize. You typically want to at least look at the performance of your model across its entire operating range, for example using [receiver operating characteristic (ROC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curves. Better yet would be to create your own utility function that explicitly models the tradeoffs in your own application and optimize that directly (e.g. are false positives and false negatives equally bad?).

If you want to automatically find suitable hyperparameters for a given task based on some criterion you choose, you should have a look at software libraries like [Optunity](http://docs.optunity.net) (an example specifically about SVMs is available [here](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notebooks/notebooks/sklearn-svc.html)).

Comment: Marc, I'm surprised by your claim about feature selection in bullet (2). I think it's fairly intuitive that many "noise" features might make training a high-performance SVM difficult. For example, see the discussion in *Elements of Statistical Learning* section 12.3.4, in which the authors suggest that the kernel itself must encode the information that only some subspace of features are useful. They also demonstrate this with some experiments on synthetic data.

Comment: The claim is based on personal experience, so call it anecdotal. I've used SVMs on numerous data sets from various domains and have never had any significant gain attributable to feature selection. Surely there are examples where it would help, but SVMs are generally quite robust against uninformative features, so I don't consider feature selection a priority when using SVM classifiers.

Comment: FWIW, I've had the same experience myself -- that is, my data are sufficiently informative and the SVM is sufficiently flexible that I can get good results without feature selection. But in combination, our two perspectives indicate that there must exist a class of problems where good results can't be achieved in the absence of selection, but might be *with* some selection.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'm not sure many such problems exist in practice, though. Another issue I have is that feature selection, hyperparameter optimization (and kernel selection) are so interrelated in the context of kernel methods that these tasks should ideally be performed jointly (i.e., not in nested loops), which most popular approaches largely ignore. Hence, another reason why I tend to shy away from feature selection when using kernel methods is that existing approaches leave much to be desired in this respect.

Comment: I certainly appreciate the dilemma! Most feature selection methods can be expressed as another kind of hyperparameter optimization method, which naturally leads to the proliferation of hyperparameters. Most people insist on unintelligent hyperparameter search methods, so that rapidly slows down model optimization.